# Polynomials are not a closed subspace of $C[0,1]$ w.r.t. the restricted $\lVert\bullet\rVert_2$ norm

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F$ be the linear subspace of $C[0,1]$ of polynomials. I need to show that $F$ is not closed in $C[0,1]$ with respect to the inner product
$\langle f,g\rangle=\int^1_0 f\bar{g} \,dx$. I have tried to show that
$\lVert T_n-f \rVert^2\to 0$ for some Taylor polynomials $T_n$ and
some $f\notin F$, but have run into problems when trying to integrate the square of a polynomial. I would appreciate any hints.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user251257 that is in the sup norm. In the $L^2$ norm, $f_n(x) = x^n \to 0$.

Comment: @nitin: oh right ... sorry :D

Comment: Are you familiar with Stone-Weierstrass theorem (i.e. any continuous function on $[0,1]$ is the uniform limit of a sequence of polynomials)?

Comment: isn't the set of polynomials dense in $L^2$? Just take any non polynomial $L^2$ function and expand it as a series of Legendre polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is that Taylor polynomials converge uniformly on compact subsets, so you don't really need to calculate **explicitly** the square. You can extimate it from above with $\left\lVert T_n-f\right\rVert_\infty^2=\max_{x\in[0,1]}\left\lvert T_n(x)-f(x)\right\rvert^2$.

For instance: 
\begin{align}p_n:[0,1]\to \Bbb R\\p_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}\end{align}

$p_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$ to $e^x$. Hence \begin{align}\int_0^1(p_n(x)-e^x)^2\,dx\le\int_0^1\left\lVert p_n-\exp\right\rVert_\infty^2\,dx\le\left\lVert p_n-\exp\right\rVert_\infty^2\to_n 0\end{align}

Comment: How do you get the second inequality?

Comment: Because, by definition $$\left\lVert p_n-\exp\right\rVert_\infty:=\max_{t\in [0,1]}\left\lvert p_n(t)-e^t\right\rvert$$ so that quantity is *always* greater than the integrand at  each point.